# Consider the equation $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = 35$. How many different solutions does this equation have if all the variables must be positive integers?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

Consider the equation $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = 35$. How many different solutions does this equation have if all the variables must be positive integers?

I don't understand this problem.I don't know whether to solve it using bit strings concept or combinations. Someone help!

Comment: Are you familiar with [combinations with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition)?

Comment: Each solution corresponds uniquely to [placing 35 starts and 3 bars between them separating 4 amounts of stars that will be the values of $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))

Comment: @totoro Not quite: 31 stars and 3 bars. Four of the stars are spoken for by the fact that the $x_i$ are positive (i.e. at least 1).

Comment: @ConnorHarris There are two situations.  The 1st theorem corresponds to the case for *positive* integers, so there are 35 $\star$s, while the 2nd theorem ... *nonnegative* integers, so there are 31 $\star$s.

Answer (score 1):

Let us take each $x_i=a_1+1$

$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=35$
$\therefore a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4=31$ ,where each $a_i$ is non-negative.

Now using the stars and bars method the answer is - $\binom{31+4-1}{4-1}\\ =\binom{34}{3}$

Answer (score 1):

For reasons of space, let's consider the following alternative problem:

> How many solutions does the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 15$ have in the positive integers?

A particular solution of this equation corresponds to the placement of $3$ addition signs in the $14$ spaces between successive ones in a row of $15$ ones. 
$$1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1$$
For instance, placing an addition sign in the fourth, seventh, and twelfth spaces gives 
$$1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1$$
which corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 4$, $x_2 = 3$, $x_3 = 5$, $x_4 = 3$.
Hence, the number of such solutions is the number of ways we can select which three of the $14$ spaces between successive ones in a row of $15$ ones will be filled with addition signs, which is 
$$\binom{14}{3}$$

> How many solutions does the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \cdots + x_k = n$ have in the positive integers?

Since a particular solution of the equation corresponds to the placement of $k - 1$ addition signs in the $n - 1$ spaces between successive ones in a row of $n$ ones, the number of solutions of the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \cdots + x_k = n$ in the positive integers is 
$$\binom{n - 1}{k - 1}$$

Comment: So, what to do, if I want to count only unordered cases? For example in your answer 1+1+1+12 and 12+1+1+1 are different, but if it's the same?

Comment: @Evgeny You are talking about partitions of a positive integer $n$ into exactly $k$ parts, the number of which is given by the [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) $S(n, k)$.

Comment: I think its something different. What is S(4, 2)? But if we will represent 4 by sum of 2 terms: 1 + 3 or 2 + 2, right?

Comment: @Evgeny Yes, you are right.  Stirling numbers of the second kind count the number of ways of placing $n$ distinct objects into $k$ indistinguishable boxes if no box is left empty, so $S(4, 2) = \binom{4}{3} + 3 = 7 > 2$ (choose which three of the four objects are together and which object is paired with a designated object).  However, you meant placing $n$ indistinguishable objects in $k$ indistinguishable boxes if no box is left empty.  For that, we need to count [restricted partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts).